# Let ScrollView only scroll when screen is touched

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView and I want this to scroll only when the user swipes the screen and it should stop if it does not touch the screen. Now when the user swipes fast and releases the screen the ScrollView moves to the other end.

How can I make it such that it only follows the swipe of the user on screen and stops if the user does not touch the screen?

Comment: Actually, you want to disable the flick input to scroll view. Maybe [this](https://learnpainless.com/android/scrollview/create-custom-scrollview-to-enable-or-disable-scrolling) can help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lalit's answer, another way of doing it would be by creating a custom class extending ScrollView and then overriding `public void fling (int velocityY);`

Just leave the method's body empty.